# How to load Image from Database by URL using Glide and Intent extras

Tags: java, android, mysql, image-processing, android-glide

I need some help trying to get my app to load an image from my SQL database using glide and Intent Extras.

Now I have done this already in a part of my app that uses adapters as i am able to attach the image-view to a view holder and manipulate it that way. Is there a way for me to do this without attaching adapters to everything?

Here's my code any help would be appreciated:
BusinessAdapter.java ------->

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BusinessesAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Businesses temp = mData.get ( position );
    holder.business_name.setText ( mData.get ( position ).getBusiness_name () );
    holder.featured_desc.setText ( mData.get ( position ).getBdesc () );
    Glide.with (mContext)
            .asBitmap ()
            .load ( mData.get ( position ).getBusiness_img () )
            .diskCacheStrategy ( DiskCacheStrategy.ALL )
            .into ( holder.featured_image );
    holder.featured_card.setOnClickListener ( v -> {
        Toast.makeText ( mContext, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show ();
        Intent intent = new Intent ( mContext, FeaturedSolocompany.class );
        intent.putExtra ( "feat_name", temp.getBusiness_name () );
        intent.putExtra ( "feat_bdesc", temp.getBdesc () );
        intent.putExtra ( "feat_image", temp.getBusiness_img () );
        mContext.startActivity ( intent );


    } );


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size ();
}


public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    LinearLayout featured_card;
    TextView business_name;
    TextView featured_desc;
    ImageView featured_image;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );
        //HOOKS
        featured_card = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.featured_card );
        business_name = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.business_name );
        featured_desc = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.featured_desc );
        featured_image = itemView.findViewById ( R.id.featured_image );
    }
}
```

Now I will show you where business adapter is going to and where the intents are going. business_name & bdesc work but business_img is not passing the image I want from the database as I need

```
public class FeaturedSolocompany extends AppCompatActivity {
List<Businesses> businessesList;
TextView business_name;
TextView bdesc;
ImageView business_img;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate ( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView ( R.layout.featuredsolopage );
    businessesList = new ArrayList<> ();
    business_name = findViewById ( R.id.feat_name );
    bdesc = findViewById ( R.id.feat_bdesc );
    business_name.setText ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "feat_name" ) );
    bdesc.setText ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "feat_bdesc" ) );
    Glide.with ( this ).load ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "feat_image" ) )
            .thumbnail ( R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground )
            .into ( business_img );
```

Again any help on this would be awesome could it be that i'm not loading it correctly maybe?

Comment: Maybe you can solve your problem using a string to recovery the data, something like: `String img = getIntent().getStringExtra("feat_bdesc"); so, at this point maybe you need to see that's the correct image. So, debug this line to corrobore

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo I have tried this:

Comment: String img = getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "feat_image" );
        Glide.with ( this ).load ( img ).into ( business_img );

Comment: ERROR:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Comment: can you write the logcat in the question?

Comment: Hi @FranqoBalsamo , I fixed the issue by setting the image view to something and then calling glide to override it

Comment: business_img.setImageResource ( R.drawable.analysis );
        Glide.with ( this ).load ( getIntent ().getStringExtra ( "feat_image" ) ).into ( business_img );